# How does YII handle the saving of post array data

Tags: yii

I currently have a checkboxlist in my form and on submitting this data it gets posted to a controller action. The data looks like this:

```
 'TraderProfileMake' => 
    array (size=1)
      'make' => 
        array (size=4)
          'CAR' => 
            array (size=6)
                0 => string 'ABARTH' (length=6)
                1 => string 'ALFA ROMEO' (length=10)
                2 => string 'ASIA WING' (length=9)
                3 => string 'B.A.W' (length=5)
                4 => string 'BACKDRAFT' (length=9)
                5 => string 'BENTLEY' (length=7)
```

How am i able to save this data without doing a loop in Yii? i am currently doing a foreach loop and then inside this loop i declare a new instance of the model or each iteration. Each value gets inserted one at a time.

Just wondering if there is a better way...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DAO](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao) writing a single SQL query to insert all rows at once while `CActiveRecord` is dedicated to deal with only one row. But this way you have to validate posted data by yourself. Unfortunatelly Yii's validators can work only with models.